# Uninstalling Debian glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2

Tags: glibc

I have a user who has upgraded his server to Debian Linux 11.7 with Debian glibc 2.31-13+deb11u6.  But the vulnerability software he uses is still picking up glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2  as being installed and listing all the vulnerabilities associated with it.  The software is not being detected when running apt-get upgrade.  How can he do a complete uninstall of glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2  or how can he investigate this?

Thank you

Comment: Which "software is not being detected when running apt-get upgrade"?

Comment: Following is what he gets when he runs apt-get upgrade.  It does not detect the older version glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2 .  The server is in French. This was translated.       apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists....Done
Reading status information.....Done
Calculation of the update.... Done
The following package was installed automatically and is no longer needed: linux-image-4.19.0-23-amd64
please use "apt autoremove" to remove it.
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated.

Comment: What is this vulnerability software?

Comment: Rapid7 InsightVM.  It identifies the OS correctly as Debian Linux 11.7 but it lists all the vulnerabilities associated with glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2.  Lists the following as proof  - 
Vulnerable software installed: Debian glibc 2.28-10+deb10u2   and following as fix -
Use `apt-get upgrade` to upgrade glibc to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to send an update.  The User was able to resolve this issue himself.

Even after the servers were upgraded to Debian Linux 11.7 they still had linux-header-4.9x and linux-kbuild9 headers.  Once they were removed InsightVM does not detect the older version.  I don't have much knowledge of Linux so this answer is directly from the user.